# How to keep original formatting when copying from Excel to Word and back to Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

Here's my problem:

1) I copy a range of values from Excel. [Copy Rows from Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U49eS.png)

2) Paste the rows into word with *Keep Source Formatting* [Paste with Keep Original Formatting into Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOS12.png)

3) Edit my rows and then copy it again. [Copy Rows from Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQpKa.png)

4) But pasting it back to Excel, rows no longer match up? [Pastes Rows into Excel, but it's messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6k60.png)

What am I doing incorrect?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Refer to this link to see if it helps   https://superuser.com/questions/1465468/how-to-keep-original-formatting-when-copying-from-excel-to-word-and-back-to-exce

Comment: Check the 3rd Screen Shot,, `1216200.3(Page11)` & `WI123644(1)` are like warped text ,, simply increase the width of the Column so both will in one Row,, and then Copy & Paste in Excel!

Comment: @Bella, the link you posted is to this post.